# How do I cross post from Automation in a Slack Workflow

Tags: slack

Imagine a Slack user is in #channel-one

A workflow uses a form to gather information in Slack.

I use the "target channel list" so users can tell me (zero or more) other channels where this announcement should *also* be made.

The workflow then "announces" the info in #channel-one. But imagine the user specified that this content should *also* be sent to #channel-two and #channel-three.

I think what I'm missing is the ability to use this "target channels" variable as the input to the "select a channel".

Anyone got a solution?

[image: target channels variable]